# UIPopoverController's UIView: How to remove shadow?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios6, xcode4.3, uipopovercontroller

Following is a snapshot of my popover:

[image]

I have an `UIViewController` (say A) that I want to show as `popoverController`. Also I want to customize popover so I am customizing the `UIPopoverBackgroundView` (say 'b' - orange background). Everything is working right except that after rounding the corners of A.view and 'b' I have a rectangular shadow line (which from the snapshot probably belongs to A.view - green background). Based on `UIView` or `UIViewController` APIs, is there any way I can remove that shadow. I am only interested in removing the black line on left, top and right of the view not the fuzzy looking shadow.

I did try:

```
[A.view.layer setShadowOpacity:0.0];
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your UIPopoverBackgroundView subclass, override the class method:

```
+ (BOOL)wantsDefaultContentAppearance
```

To return `NO`. This prevents the drawing of the inner shadow as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIPopoverBackgroundView/wantsDefaultContentAppearance).

Comment: Thanks. It did remove that line shadow and I understood what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the call for [super layoutSubviews] in your layoutSubviews method.

Overriding wantsDefaultContentAppearance and returning NO did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control the shadow of a `UIPopoverController` directly.  Your options are:

1. Roll your own kind of popover.
2. Subclass `UIPopoverBackgroundView` and provide your own graphics for the frame of the popover.  Contrary to the official documentation, the shadow doesn't get drawn on for you when you subclass `UIPopoverBackgroundView`.  Here's a great post on how to do this: http://blog.andrewkolesnikov.com/custom-background-color-tint-for-uipopover-64835

Comment: I am already subclassing UIPopoverBackgroundView class as mentioned in question. Thanks for your answer anyways. jrturton answer below was helpful getting what I want. Thanks you.